# Custom proportional spacing in UIStackView without of additional subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, spacing, proportions

I know that I can add transparent subviews to `UIStackView` and set their widths with constraints. The problem is if I want to hide some opaque subviews all the spaces between them remain (and I don't know how to "disable" these spaces properly).

I found `setCustomSpacing(_:after:)`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2866023-setcustomspacing

The problem is it sets constant spacing but in my case opaque subviews have constant width and spacing between them varies.

Then I found `customSpacing(after:)` and tried to override it:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2865827-customspacing

It seems to be the most appropriate solution for me but the problem is the overriden method is never called.

So are there normal ways to add subviews into `UIStackView` with proportional spacing and allow to hide these subviews simultaneously with their spacing?

Comment: "but in my case opaque subviews have constant width and spacing between them varies." How does the spacing vary? Please be *specific*.

Comment: @Sweeper 4 views, 3 spacings between them. `spacingView1.width = spacingView2.width * multiplier1`, `spacingView1.width = spacingView3.width * multiplier2`. This is how it is implemented now with additional views

Comment: What is `spacingView2.width` equal to?

Comment: @Sweeper `spacingView1.width = Constant1`, `spacingView2.width = Constant2` and etc.

Comment: This is confusing. You said these spacings are not constants and now you are saying they are. Anyway, if you want them to be dynamic, you should be able to just do the calculation and set them in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't mention it because in my opinion opaque view' width is usually specified manually or exactly fits its content size. If you use default constraint priorities and both spacing and opaque views width varies then you will get an error because XIB/Swift doesn't understand how to layout views.
I got another idea - usually opaque views and spacings alternate so I could for example iterate all subviews and set `evenView.isHidden = nearestOddView.isHidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your spacings varies dynamically, depending on the dimensions of other views, set the spacings in `layoutSubviews`, or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if you are in a VC. These are the methods that will be called when some view's dimensions change. There, you can do whatever calculations you like, and compute a value for each view's spacing.

For example, here I have created a stack view with 3 labels. The spacing between the first and second labels is equal to 1/10 of the stack view's width, and the spacing between the second and third labels is equal to 1/20 of the stack view's width (aka one half of the first).

```
var stack: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    func makeLabel(_ text: String) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.text = text
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }
    stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [makeLabel("Foo Bar"), makeLabel("Something"), makeLabel("Else")])
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stack)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.centerYAnchor),
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
    ])
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    stack.setCustomSpacing(stack.bounds.width / 10, after: stack.arrangedSubviews[0])
    stack.setCustomSpacing(stack.bounds.width / 20, after: stack.arrangedSubviews[1])
}
```